# Valor padrão para coluna do tipo Datetime

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, datetime

Tenho uma tabela que possui o campo `DataRegistro` do tipo `Datetime`.
Estou utilizando EntityFramework para gerar o banco de dados (**não estou utilizadno code first**) adiciono a propriedade **Computed** para que a coluna seja preenchida automaticamente, mas continuo recebendo mensagemd e erro ao tentar inserir um novo objeto.

Gostaria de resolver diretamente pelo EF sem ter que adicionar scripts/trigger no banco para corrigir o problema.

Alguma sugestão?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como tu estás usando `Model first` uma alternativa seria criar uma classe `partial` e criar um construtor que inicialize esse campo. Ex.:

```
public partial CursoDisciplina 
{
    public CursoDisciplina()
    {
        this.DataRegistro = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```